# Three Images in a Single Div in Bootstrap as shown in Image Below and Enlarge Image on hover

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to Display Three Image in a Single Div as shown below, and on hover on particular image the image has to enlarge.
please help me.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img1.jpg" alt="thumb01" class="style">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <img src="img2.jpg" alt="thumb01" class="ch">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <img src="img3.jpg" alt="thumb01" class="ch">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ch { 
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
} 
.ch:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
    opacity: 2;
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried till now?

Comment: Code                                                                                                             <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="img1.jpg" alt="thumb01" class="style">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                  <img src="img2.jpg" alt="thumb01" class="ch">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                  <img src="img3.jpg" alt="thumb01" class="ch">
              </div></div></div></div>

Comment: css  .ch {
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

        .ch:hover {
            transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
            opacity: 2;
        }